# R to plot PCoA based on cmd function with environmental vectors

Tags: r, vector, cmd, pca

I need to make a PCoA plot (cmd scale) based on a dissimilarity matrix (vegdist, method Bray) with environmental vectors.

I got as far as the cmd PCoA plot, however, I have no idea how to plot vectors of environmental variables.

Should they be put in a separate file. Is the envfit function used and how as I am a beginner?

If someone can give me a step-by-step on how to do this, it would be wonderful.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A good tip when asking questions is showing what have you tried, i.e. documentation you found googling, some code you tried, etc. This will increase your chance to get a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many free available resources out there, with step-by-step manuals.
For example the [vegan-vignettes](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/vegan/doc/), Roeland Kindt's ['Tree diversity analysis'](http://www.worldagroforestry.org/downloads/publications/PDFs/MN08242.PDF) and many more...

The book by Borchard ([Numerical ecology with R](http://www.bio.umontreal.ca/numecolR/)) is also very good.

Here is a starter:

```
require(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)

str(dune)
str(dune.env)

# CMD
cmd <- cmdscale(vegdist(dune, method="bray"))
# Plot CMD
ordiplot(cmd)
# Fit environmental variables
fit_env <- envfit(ord=cmd, env=dune.env)

# plot environmental variables with p < 0.05
plot(fit_env, p.max = 0.05)

# add smooth surface for A1
ordisurf(cmd, dune.env$A1, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does anyone know how I would set up the dune.env file. For example, do I make columns with the first being names, the second being env factor 1, the third column being env factor 2, etc...  Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes, dune.env is a data.frame with the variables in columns. Note that the rows must correspond to the rows in your abundance data.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help, I was able to do it. I just had an additional question. Should the averaged environmental factors be plotted per group, or should the individual environmental factors be plotted per sample. I thought I had heard someone saying that the average should be plotted. Thank you!

Comment: If you like my anwer, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes, I did. Don't know what I would have done. So are the averaged values for the env factors plotted, or are they individual values per station.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, nor do I know what you mean by 'averaged values'. Please follow @Giulio Muscarello and post a reproducible example.